# Update tableView in Controller1 after method in Controller2 swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I am learning swift on my own and I am running into a block. Lets imagine a login situation. If the user is logged in, the navigation menu shows 2 options in the table view. If the user is not, the menu shows 1 option. But the login happens in a different page and controller. 
My problem is that when the user logs in, the login page is dismissed but the menu is not updated, until I close the app in Xcode and rerun it.
This is the method in the LoginController:

```
func saveUserAsLoggedIn(name: String){
        // add user login to user defaults. Works perfect.
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        MenuController().updateMenu() // this is calling a method in the menuController
}
```

and the updateMenu() method basically refreshes the tableview containing the options

```
func updateMenu(){
      self.menuTableView.beginUpdates()
      self.menuTableView.endUpdates()
}
```

but it throws this error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I know this error is because it is calling the self in MenuController when the page is not loaded to the screen but that is the only way to update the menu. How can I go about this? Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: MenuController().updateMenu() <- yes this si calling the method on the class but it seems like it is a new instance of that `MenuController`

Comment: What way did you implement the navigation of the login->menu?

Comment: @AndreiDurnea well the user clicks on one of the cells in the menu, and a segue shows the Login page, and then when it is done, I did a self.dismiss for the login page to go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple problem, the error is thrown not because of the reason you think.

```
MenuController().updateMenu()
```

This line of code is creating a new instance of MenuController CLASS and since the VIEW of the instance isn't loaded yet (because it's not in view stack yet). It's menuTableView outlet is `nil`.

So the issue is that you don't have the right instance of the menuTableView to update. In other words your MenuController and LoginController class instances aren't communicating properly.

There are three ways I see using which you can fix this issue,

1. **Use a Delegate**: Read up on delegate methods if you are not sure about them. It's one of the ways classes can communicate with each other. 
   In this approach, you'll have the instance of MenuController in LoginController so that you can directly call and update the menuTableView
2. **Use a closure**: Again, please read up on closures if you aren't familiar with it since it is one of the powerful tools provided by swift. In this apprach, you'll define a bunch of statements to be executed in MenuController, but the execution of the statement is triggered by LoginController.
3. **Pass the tableView instance**: Or you can just get reckless and pass the instance of the tableView from MenuController to LoginController so that you can reload it from LoginController. But, I wouldn't prefer this.

I would personally choose to use a closure since I'm soo fond of them. But many of my colleagues and seniors might say that delegate is the proper way to do this. Again, it's completely upto you since you are the developer.

Best of luck.

Comment: thank you so much! I was able to implement a delegate using this [tutorial](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/) and it works perfectly!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could be of help :D. Please do contact me if there is anything :).